# How will new players be attracted if the regulars are experienced?

Tags: plot-explanation, mollys-game

In *Molly's Game* (2017), Molly used to work as a waitress at the nightclub and now she is running poker games
She reached out to the nightclub workers with the intention of convincing them to direct
potential players to her poker games:

> Molly: If they say they're interested in poker, you give them
> my number. I vet them. If they end up playing in a game,
> I'll give you $1,000 the first time they play, $500 every time
> after that. **Be sure to mention that these guys are all regulars**.

How will new players be attracted if the regulars are experienced?

Comment: Because it gives the impression that these aren't pro-level players, and hence an easy mark for wannabe card sharps.